# Delete the record using jquery when click submit button

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, delete-record

I want to delete my record from database using jquery. when I save my file I use the 
following code,

The record Id's there..

**Jobs**

**Controller Code**

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        Job job = _repository.GetJob(id);
        if (job != null)
        {
            _repository.DeleteJobLanguages(id);
            _repository.DeleteJobLocations(id);
            _repository.DeleteJobPreferredIndustries(id);
            _repository.DeleteJobRequiredQualifications(id);
            _repository.DeleteJobRoles(id);
            _repository.DeleteJobskills(id);
            _repository.DeleteJob(id);
        }

        return View(job);

    }
```

**Jquery**
    Dial4Jobz.Job.Add = function (sender) {
    var form = $(sender).parent();
    var data = form.serialize();

```
var url = form.attr('action');
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        Dial4Jobz.Common.ShowMessageBar(response.Message);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        Dial4Jobz.Common.ShowMessageBar(xhr.statusText);
    }
});
return false;
```

};

Here when I click submit button, it calls the jquery. Then it shows some error. How to write code in jquery for delete?

Comment: Delete record from where, exactly?

Comment: All in all, you'll need to write server-side procedure, that takes some unique ID of your record and deletes it from wherever it is.

Comment: It really depends on the implementation of your server side...

Comment: i updated my question.Please take a view

Answer (score 2):

You could have a server side controller action which will take the id of the record that needs to be deleted:

```
[HttpDelete]
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    repository.Delete(id);
    return Json(new { id = id });
}
```

and then the same way you could use AJAX to invoke it:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "DELETE",
    url: url,
    data: { id: '123' }, // <-- put the id of the record you want to delete here
    success: function (response) {

    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
    }
});
```